# Editing a TextView Object in code

Tags: java, android, xml

I had an idea finally for testing my knowledge for android application development. As it turns out Android development is pretty complex but once you understand the flow of things it gets easier. Anyway I 'think' I have everything set up correctly, via the XML and Java, but the TextView Objects are for some reason not either accepting the values I am giving them or I am calling the methods that edit them in the wrong way. I do not know which one it is however and this is the reason I am posting here. I also did check numerous other topics through links but haven't either understood what I am doing wrong or am completely missing the point.

```
  Activity Popup (Main)

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".Popup"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/LyOutInstructions">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Instructions:"
        android:id="@+id/txtInstruction"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="monospace" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mov"
        android:id="@+id/btnMov"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sub"
        android:id="@+id/btnSub"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Int"
        android:id="@+id/btnInt"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:enabled="true" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:id="@+id/LyOutRegisters">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Registers:"
        android:id="@+id/txtRegisters"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="EAX"
        android:id="@+id/btnRegEAX"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:enabled="false" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="EBX"
        android:id="@+id/btnRegEBX"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:enabled="false" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ECX"
        android:id="@+id/btnRegECX"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:enabled="false" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="EDX"
        android:id="@+id/btnRegEDX"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:enabled="false" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
    android:id="@+id/LyOutRegisterNames">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="EAX:"
        android:id="@+id/txtRegNameEAX" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="EBX:"
        android:id="@+id/txtRegNameEBX" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ECX:"
        android:id="@+id/txtRegNameECX" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="EDX:"
        android:id="@+id/txtRegNameEDX" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="282dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:id="@+id/LyOutRegisterOutput">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtRegValueEAX"
        android:text="@string/Instruction_EAX"
        android:editable="false"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtRegValueEBX"
        android:text="@string/Instruction_EBX"
        android:editable="false"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtRegValueECX"
        android:text="@string/Instruction_ECX"
        android:editable="false"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtRegValueEDX"
        android:text="@string/Instruction_EDX"
        android:editable="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
GetData (Popup)

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="350dp"
android:id="@+id/DataLayout"
android:layout_height="250dp"
android:background="@drawable/pop"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/GetDataTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter your Data" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/GetDataInstruction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/GetData"
    android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnEnterData"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter Data"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

```
strings

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">Basic Assembler</string>
<string name="Instruction_EAX"> </string>
<string name="Instruction_EBX"> </string>
<string name="Instruction_ECX"> </string>
<string name="Instruction_EDX"> </string>
<string name="GetData">Please enter your Data...</string>
<string name="title">Assemble</string>
<string name="app_settings">Settings</string>
```

```
Popup.java
package com.wtf.demo;
import com.wtf.demo.GetData;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Intent;


public class Popup extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_popup);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    }
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();
    Intent ShowDialog = new Intent(Popup.this, GetData.class);
    if (id == R.id.btnAdd) {
        Data.Instruction = "add";
        startActivity(ShowDialog);
    } else if (id == R.id.btnSub) {
        Data.Instruction = "sub";
        startActivity(ShowDialog);
    } else if (id == R.id.btnMov) {
        Data.Instruction = "mov";
        startActivity(ShowDialog);
    } else if (id == R.id.btnInt) {
        Data.Instruction = "int";
        startActivity(ShowDialog);
    }
    Update();
}

private void Update() {
    new Tools(Data.Instruction, Data.CachedData);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_popup, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class Tools {
    public Tools(Object X, Object Y) {
        Validate(X + " " + Y);
    }

    private void Validate(Object _Data) {
        int i;
        if (_Data != null && !_Data.toString().equals(" ")) {
            String[] Temp = _Data.toString().split(",");
            if (Temp.length > 2) {
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                System.exit(1);
            } else {
                String Value = null;
                boolean FirstValue = false;
                for (i = 0; i < Temp.length; i++) {
                    String _Value = Temp[i].trim().toLowerCase();
                    if (!_Value.equals(" ")) {
                        if (Arrays.asList(Data.Registers).contains(_Value)) {
                            if (!FirstValue) {
                                FirstValue = true;
                                Value = _Value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (Value != null) {
                    Commit((Object) Temp[0], (Object) Temp[1], Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Commit(Object X, Object Y, String Value) {
        TextView txtRegEAX, txtRegEBX, txtRegECX, txtRegEDX;
        txtRegEAX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRegValueEAX);
        txtRegEBX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRegValueEBX);
        txtRegECX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRegValueECX);
        txtRegEDX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRegValueEDX);
        //Int Destination, Source : Intel Syntax
        if (Value.equals(X)){
            if (Arrays.asList(Data.Registers).contains(Y)){
                if (Value.equals("eax")){ _Commit(Data.EAX, Y); }
                else if (Value.equals("ebx")){ _Commit(Data.EBX, Y); }
                else if (Value.equals("ecx")){ _Commit(Data.ECX, Y); }
                else if (Value.equals("edx")){ _Commit(Data.EDX, Y); }
            }
            else {
                if (Value.equals("eax")){ Commit(Data.EAX, (Integer)Y); }
                else if (Value.equals("ebx")){ Commit(Data.EBX, (Integer)Y); }
                else if (Value.equals("ecx")){ Commit(Data.ECX, (Integer)Y); }
                else if (Value.equals("edx")){ Commit(Data.EDX, (Integer)Y); }
            }
        }
        txtRegEAX.setText(String.valueOf(Data.EAX));
        txtRegEBX.setText(String.valueOf(Data.EBX));
        txtRegECX.setText(String.valueOf(Data.ECX));
        txtRegEDX.setText(String.valueOf(Data.EDX));
    }

    private void _Commit(Object X, Object Y) {
        if (Y.equals("eax")) Commit(X, Data.EAX);
        else if (Y.equals("ebx")) Commit(X, Data.EBX);
        else if (Y.equals("ecx")) Commit(X, Data.ECX);
        else if (Y.equals("edx")) Commit(X, Data.EDX);
    }

    private void Commit(Object X, int Y) {
        int x = (Integer)X;
        if (Data.Instruction.equals("mov")) X = Y + 0;
        else if (Data.Instruction.equals("add")) X = x + Y;
        else if (Data.Instruction.equals("sub")) X = x - Y;
        else if (Data.Instruction.equals("int")) X = x + 0;
    }
}

public static class Data {
    public static int EAX = 0;
    public static int EBX = 0;
    public static int ECX = 0;
    public static int EDX = 0;
    public static String Instruction = null;
    public static String CachedData = null;
    public static String[] Registers = new String[]{"eax", "ebx", "ecx", "edx"};
}
}

GetData.java
package com.wtf.demo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Gravity;
import com.wtf.demo.Popup;

/**
 * Created by Ghost on 11/4/2014.
 */
public class GetData extends Activity {
EditText GetData;
Button EnterData;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.getdata_popup);
    final Button btnEnterData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnterData);
    GetData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.GetDataInstruction);
    btnEnterData.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String Cache = GetData.getText().toString();
            if (Cache != null) {
                Popup.Data.CachedData = Cache;
                Done();
            }
            else finish();
        }
    });
}

private void Done() {
    finish();
}
}
```

Edit #1: I just realized that for some reason my copy/paste was messed up and I posted the activity_popup.xml twice, I am in the process of Debugging now. Why the downvote?

Edut #2: If you do not manage your Activities you end up with essentially spaghetti code, not linked and ugly. I could have just make my update method public, but that would have not solved this issue and would reinforce the former. Will update when I finish refactoring correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`txtRegEAX.setText()` should work, so I'd recommend you put in some breakpoints to figure out if the values are empty or if the code ever ran. Please tell me what you figure out.

Comment: When you use more than one activity you need your activity control methods (onResume/Pause/Stop) to manage the current activity while the other is executing. Thank you for encouraging me to further experiment. I will posted the updated code later on.

Answer (score 0):

There is no EditText in your layout, you can't do anything with textview, use edittext to edit while running your app